# How do you get the second item for each JSON object without using the property's name?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, salesforce, soql

In the below segment, I'm wanting to get the second property within all `records` in this JSON file. If I replace the `[1]` in  `jObjects.SelectTokens("records[*].[1]")` with `.Name`, I get the correct output, but it is limiting it to only the name.

```
If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
    Try
        Dim jObjects As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
        For Each tk As JToken In jObjects.SelectTokens("records[*].[1]")
            jsonList.Add(tk)
        Next
        For Each strng As String In jsonList
            txtQueryOutput.AppendText(strng + vbCrLf)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End If
```

The app accepts queries in the form of SOQL and then I'm taking the response and parsing it. So if I query `SELECT name FROM contact`, I get this:

```
"totalSize" : 21,
"done" : true,
"records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Contact/0031U00000GtLxDQAV"
    },
    "Name" : "Jack Rogers"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Contact/0031U00000GlhHTQAZ"
    },
    "Name" : "Rose Gonzalez"
  },
```

I can then query `SELECT phone FROM contact` and get the same except `Name` in the JSON response will be `Phone`. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do by using the index `[1]` to get all second entries in each object?

**UPDATE #1**

To clarify, I'm wanting to get every property value *after* the `attributes` array in the `records` object. So if I query `Name, Phone, Email`, then I want all those property values, but not the attributes array values. Here is a sample of what I'm trying/wanting to do, although this doesn't work and crashes on the attributes array:

```
Dim data As List(Of JToken) = jObjects.Children().ToList

For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "records"
            For Each subItem As JProperty In item
                Select Case subItem.Name
                    Case "attributes"
                        'skip
                    Case Else
                        txtQueryOutput.AppendText(subItem.Value)
                End Select
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

Essentially, I want to skip over the attributes array and just get every value after it.

Comment: I don't know soql but can you do: SELECT name as result FROM contact  ?

Comment: @the_lotus I tried that, but it doesn't appear to be valid. I get "malformed query" as the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all property values from the objects in the `records` array excluding `attributes` using a LINQ query like this:

```
Dim jObjects As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)

Dim values As List(Of String) = jObjects("records") _
    .Children(Of JObject) _
    .SelectMany(Function(jo) jo.Properties()) _
    .Where(Function(jp) jp.Name <> "attributes") _
    .Select(Function(jp) CStr(jp.Value)) _
    .ToList()

txtQueryOutput.AppendText(String.Join(vbCrLf, values))
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ubqVnJ